# Scope chain first looks to __parent__ or to __proto__?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, spidermonkey

[Here](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/#scope-chain) I found information hot to works scope chain:

> ...before we go to the **parent** link, first **proto** chain is
> considered.
>
> Notice, that not in all implementations the global object inherits
> from the Object.prototype. The behavior described on the figure (with
> referencing “non-defined” variable x from the global context) may be
> tested e.g. in SpiderMonkey.

I use Firefox browser for testing, but, when I set global variable `x`, and set to `Object.prototype` property `x` and do `a()` I've got 4. Why, if first we go to `proto`?

```
var x = 1;
Object.prototype.x = 2;

var a = function () {
  y = 3;
  return this.y + this.x;
};

a.x;  // 2
a();  // 4
```

Comment: Your example code makes absolutely no sense. Why would you expect it to yield `6` and `15`, instead of `2` and `4` as it should (admittedly, the result of `a()` is complicated)? Also that example is nowhere mentioned on the page you linked.

Comment: I made mistake, sorry

Comment: `Object.prototype.x` is about the last place JS looks for `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've cited the beginning of that paragraph, not the end:

> At code execution, a scope chain may be **augmented using `with` statement** and `catch` clause objects.

So what your sentence refers to are only *object environment records* - scope objects in which variables live. Those are typically imaginary, described for specification purposes only (and can [only be observed in Rhino](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-2-variable-object/#feature-of-implementations-property-__parent__)), but the `with` statement makes an exception and prepends an actual JS object to the scope chain.

If you check out the example, you will find the `with` statement right there. The gist:

```
Object.prototype.x = "inherited object property";
var x = "parent scope variable";
with ({}) {
    alert(x); // you bet what it yields
}
```

---

> When I set global variable `x`, and set `Object.prototype.x` property, why doesn't it get the prototype value?

By using [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in a function that is called plainly (`a()`), you are referring to the global object. It is indeed the object for the object environment record of the global scope, which means that all global variables live there as properties.

Now why does accessing `x` on that object (regardless whether by variable `x` or property `this.x`) bring up `1` not `2`? Because the global variable with the value `1` is an **own property** of the object. The prototype chain will only be traversed if the property is not already found!